# ERROR: "Exception caught by gesture" in Flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

I am trying to store data in a class to store this information and use them later, but I am getting this error message and can't find out what I have to change to make it work. Here is a simplified version of my code where I get the same error.

````
class LUI {
  String lui;

  LUI({
    this.lui,
  });
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  final LUI data;

  Test({
    Key key,
    this.data,
  });

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
                child: Container(
                    child: TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            ))),
            TextButton(
              child: Text('add information'),
              onPressed: () {
                _sendresult(context);
                print(widget.data.lui);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _sendresult(BuildContext context) {
    final result = _controller.text;
    print(result);
    setState(() {
      widget.data.lui = result;
    });
  }
}```
````

Comment: [and here is the Error Message I get when i run this app:][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs0yy.png

Comment: Where are you creating the instance of `Test` class. Can you confirm whethere you are sending a value for the `data` parameter from there. From your error it seems like you dont

Comment: Thank you! You're totally right. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, the `Test` class expects a value to be passed for the `data` argument. However as you are not passing any value to that while creating the instance, which makes the field to remain null.

Later when you access the same field in the `print(widget.data.lui);` it results in a `null pointer exception`. As you already ahve figured, the soultion is to pass a value to `data`.

However, you can write your code in a better way so that you can catch this error in the compile time rather than waiting till the runtime.

**Approach 1: (With Null-Safety enabled)**

Use the keyword `required` to specify the filed is a must e.g.

```
  Test({
    Key key,
    required this.data,
  });
```

Now, with this, creating an instance like `Test()` with arguments input will throw compilation errors compalining about the missing input argument.

**Approach 2: (Without Null-Safety enabled)**

Use the annotation `@required` to specify the filed is a required e.g.

```
  Test({
    Key key,
    @required this.data,
  });
```

In this case, failing to pass an argument will throw a compile time warning (yellow line highlighter) which unlike the above case will inform you but will not block your execution.

Answer (score 0):

I had to send a value for the data parameter from where I create the instance of the Test class. Thanks, Sisir for your answer.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Basis',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.red,
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            headline1: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 40,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        home: Test(data: new LUI()));
  }
}
```